# Zend Framework - Install an older version

Tags: php, zend-framework, version, downgrade

I've already install ZF3. But I'm working in a company that use only ZF2, and I must be able to use Doctrine too. Since the version 3 can't work with doctrine, I have to either downgrade it, or install an older version.

But I can't see how to do it since http://framework.zend.com/download/archives does not exist anymore ?

I've tried to use   `composer install` and change the composer.json to this:

```
{   
"name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
"description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "zf2"
],
"homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
"repositories": [
    {
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "https://packages.zendframework.com/"
}
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.*"
}
}
```

But then I only got the vendor and composer.lock, and I can't create the project in the same folder since it is not empty.

How do I do this ?

Thank you in advance for your time!

PS:

> I'm using php 5.6, with Apache 2.2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found https://framework.zend.com/downloads/archives and could download version 2.4.9 but I'm a bit lost about how to install it correctly. By the way, I'm only looking for the Skeleton Application.

**SOLUTION:**
Just add the version number (here 2.5) at the end of the command :

```
composer create-project -sdev --repository-url="https://packages.zendframework.com" zendframework/skeleton-application ./ 2.5
```

Comment: Thank very much, ;)

Comment: Good. Thank a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can also install directly via composer command:

```
$ composer create-project zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install ^2.5
```