# How to install zend framework 2.4.11 skeleton application

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to install **ZF 2.4.11** using https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/ref/installation.html , but after completing the installation, the **home page** displays **ZF version 3.0.2 DEV**.

How can I correctly install **Zend Skeleton Application of desired version (2.4.11)**.

I am using `php 5.6`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zend Framework - Install an older version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654741/zend-framework-install-an-older-version)

Answer (score 10):

Execute following:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git zf2
$ cd zf2
$ git checkout origin/release-2.4
```

You will get a message:

> HEAD is now at ff7b0e4... Pin to 2.4.11 series

After that just run:

```
$ composer install
```

you will have ZF 2.4.11 installed.

*In the future you will got the latest version.*

Answer (score 2):

1. git Clone the application in folder skeleton

> git clone https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git
>   skeleton

2.cd to skeleton application

> cd skeleton application

3. checkout the release 2.4.11 as:

> git checkout origin/release-2.4

after installing composer from https://getcomposer.org/ you can run the below comand that will automatic create a project with zend 2.4

```
composer create-project zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install ^2.4
```

or

```
 php composer.phar create-project zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install ^2.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Without cloning via git command, you can install directly via composer command:

```
$ composer create-project zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install 2.4
```

Just put the ZF version you desired.
One line command.

Comment: You have to specify 2.4.11 as 2.4 alone doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It's work fine:

```
composer create-project zendframework/skeleton-application path to install ^2.2
```