# How can I install Zend Framework 2.4.13 with composer?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, composer-php, zend-framework3

I am Ruby on Rails developer.
In it for a particular Ruby version their is a rails version to suit it.

But now I am using Zend Framework 2 requires `PHP 5.6` or later which is fine.
Now it has a composer and it has its own versions. I have tried to download zend framework 2 according to documention at https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html I always end up with Zend framework 3.

Also Try to download sketon app from archive at https://framework.zend.com/downloads/archives But they do not have any public folder in them.
But actualy I want `zend framework 2.4.13` do not know to get it done. Please help.

The command:
composer create-project -n -sdev zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install always create a ZendFramework 3 app is their is a command to create a project of zendfrmaework 2.

I have `php 5.6` install with `composer 1.4.2`

Please provide the tutorial link which is start teaching  from ground zero/beginning.

Comment: Perhaps a post install command?  `zf create project foo`.  But it might be a case of chicken and egg.  As I doubt `zf` will be in your path at that point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zend Framework - Install an older version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654741/zend-framework-install-an-older-version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the instruction here [How to install Zend Framework 2.4](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41932986/949273) 
and you will got 2.4.13 version.

Just check it with:

```
$ composer show -i
```

For begging tutorials my advice is to use latest version (ZF3).

For old version 2.* you can find several books, just google it.

Answer (score 2):

Without cloning via git command, you can install directly via composer command:

```
$ composer create-project zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install ^2.4
```

Just put the ZF version you desired.

Answer (score 1):

Run these steps for get Zend Framework Skeleton 2.4.13 version:

```
git clone https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git skeleton
cd skeleton
git checkout origin/release-2.4
php composer update
```

Run these steps for get Zend Framework Skeleton 2.5.1 version:

```
composer create-project zendframework/skeleton-application goforzf251 ^2.5.1
```

You can replace ^2.5.1 for ^2.2, ^2.1, etc...

> The ^ (caret)operator behaves sticks closer to semantic versioning,
> and will always allow non-breaking updates. For example ^1.2.3 is
> equivalent to >=1.2.3 <2.0.0 as none of the releases until 2.0 should
> break backwards compatibility. For pre-1.0 versions it also acts with
> safety in mind and treats ^0.3 as >=0.3.0 <0.4.0.
> https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range-